# @Module.subcomponents on Android

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have the following (simplified) setup of 1 Application and 1 Activity, 1 Parent Component and 1 Subcomponent:

**Application**:

```
public class ExampleApp extends Application {
    private AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    ActivityComponent.Builder getActivityComponentBuilder();
}
```

**Activity Subcomponent**:

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = {ActivityModule1.class, ActivityModule2.class})
public interface ActivityComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);


    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder binding1(@Named("binding1") int binding1);

        @BindsInstance
        Builder binding2(@Named("binding2") int binding2);

        ActivityComponent build();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    TheObjectIWant theObjectIWant1, theObjectIWant2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityComponent component = ((ExampleApp) getApplication()).getAppComponent()
                .getActivityComponentBuilder()
                .binding1(100)
                .binding2(200)
                .build();

        component.inject(this);

        theObjectIWant1.doStuff();
        theObjectIWant2.doStuff();
    }
}
```

I would now like to refactor this same example to use the `Module.subcomponents` attribute instead of the `Subcomponent.Builder` factory method.
For this, I remove `getActivityComponentBuilder()` from the `AppComponent` and add the `Module.subcomponents` attribute to the `AppModule`:

**AppComponent (new)**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

}
```

**AppModule (new)**:

```
@Module(subcomponents = ActivityComponent.class)
public abstract class AppModule {
    [...]
}
```

My question is pretty simple. How do I now get the `ActivityComponent.Builder` into the `MainActivity`? I can't constructor inject the `MainActivity`, so there's only really field injection left:

**MainActivity (new, theory)**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    ActivityComponent.Builder activityComponentBuilder
    @Inject
    TheObjectIWant theObjectIWant1, theObjectIWant2;

    ((ExampleApp) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this)
    [...]
}
```

But this will not work, since the `AppComponent` can't inject `theObjectIWant1` and `theObjectIWant1`. They only come from the `ActivityComponent`.

So is this approach just not suitable here? Since this is more of a theoretical question, **please ignore dagger.android here** and assume we want to handle this without it.